# How to put objects in an array into new array sorting by date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I want to use SectionList in React Native. Datas that SectionList needs to render looks like this:

```
sections=[
 {
   date: 'May 24 2019', 
   data: [
     {
       id:1,
       msg: 'msg1',
       date: 'May 24 2019'
     },
     {
       id:2,
       msg: 'msg2',
       date: 'May 24 2019'
     },
 ]},
 {
   date: 'May 25 2019', 
   data: [
     {
       id:3,
       msg: 'msg1',
       date: 'May 25 2019'
     },
     {
       id:4,
       msg: 'msg2',
       date: 'May 25 2019'
     },
 ]},
];
```

But data that I receive from server looks like this:

```
data:[
  {
       id:1,
       msg: 'msg1',
       date: 'May 24 2019'
  },
  {
       id:2,
       msg: 'msg2',
       date: 'May 24 2019'
  },
  {
       id:3,
       msg: 'msg1',
       date: 'May 25 2019'
  },
  {
       id:4,
       msg: 'msg1',
       date: 'May 25 2019'
  },
];
```

So how can I convert "data" to look like "sections". 
I appreciate your help. And sorry for my English.

Comment: The wrapping object literals `{}` in your output are wrong. They should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Use `reduce()` to build up an an object whose keys will different dates and values will be array containing items
- Then get values of that object using `Object.values()`
- Then use `map()` on that and add additional property `date` and return the object.

```js
const data = [ { id:1, msg: 'msg1', date: 'May 24 2019' }, { id:2, msg: 'msg2', date: 'May 24 2019' }, { id:3, msg: 'msg1', date: 'May 25 2019' }, { id:4, msg: 'msg1', date: 'May 25 2019' }, ]

const res = Object.values(
                  data.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a.date] = (ac[a.date] || []).concat(a),ac),{})
             ).map(x => ({data:[...x],date:x[0].date}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the actual grouping and then extract the values via Object.values:

```js
let data = [ { id:1, msg: 'msg1', date: 'May 24 2019' }, { id:2, msg: 'msg2', date: 'May 24 2019' }, { id:3, msg: 'msg1', date: 'May 25 2019' }, { id:4, msg: 'msg1', date: 'May 25 2019' }, ];

let result = data.reduce((r,{ date, ...other}) => {
  r[date] = r[date] || { date, data: [] }
  r[date].data = [...r[date].data, { date, ...other }]
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        msg: 'msg1',
        date: 'May 24 2019'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        msg: 'msg2',
        date: 'May 24 2019'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        msg: 'msg1',
        date: 'May 25 2019'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        msg: 'msg1',
        date: 'May 25 2019'
    },
];

let result = {}

data.map(val=>{
    if(result[val.date]){
        return result[val.date] = {...result[val.date], value: [...result[val.date].value, val]}
    }else{
        return result[val.date] = {date: val.date, value: [val]}
    }
})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```